# Serial Port Communication using RS-485 converter and server in C#

Tags: c#, serial-port

I'm trying to build an application that can communicate with server using serial port communication.

Scenario:

I has my laptop that is attached with electric meter (act as a server) through RS-485 converter and USB. Now I want to open a port and send the initial command for communication with server, and expect server sends some response.

Here is my code

```
void main(string args[])
{
    SerialPort sp = new SerialPort();
    sp.PortName = "COM5";
    sp.BaudRate = 9600;
    ... // other parameters i.e. Parity, StopBits
    // Databits etc
    sp.Open();
    sp.DataReceived = myPortDataReceived();
    sp.WriteLine("/?!\r\n");
}
public static void myPortDataReceived(object sender, SerialPortDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort myPort = (SerialPort)sender;
    String data = myPort.ReadExisting();
    Console.WriteLine("Data Received");
    Console.WriteLine(data);
}
```

When I run the program there is no output. It means object `myPort` reads nothing.

I am new in programming and have no idea why it happened.

Any idea is really very appropriated.

Thanks

**Update 1**

I modify my code and run it but it cannot go to event handler method.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;

namespace Communication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SerialPort sp = new SerialPort();
            sp.PortName = "COM5";
            sp.Open();
            // check port is open or not
            if (sp.IsOpen==true)
                Console.WriteLine("Port is open");
            // set the port parameters
            sp.BaudRate = 9600;

            sp.DtrEnable = true;
            sp.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            sp.Parity = Parity.None;
            sp.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            sp.DataBits = 8;
            // write some command on port
            sp.WriteLine("?/!\r\n");
            // make DataReceived event handler
            sp.DataReceived += sp_DataReceived;
            //Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
            //Console.ReadLine();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static void sp_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I am in event handler");
            SerialPort sPort = (SerialPort)sender;
            String data = sPort.ReadExisting();
            foreach (char ch in data)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ch);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And can I put `sPort` as `while(true) {String data = sPort.ReadExisting(); Console.WriteLine(data); }`

Comment: please reply ,,,,

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is incorrect for the event handler. It should be:

```
        sp.DataReceived += myPortDataReceived;
```

The handler should have the following signature:

```
        void myPortDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
```

Once you fix that, also verify your parity, databits, and stopbits are all correct. Those are important and cannot be glossed over.

I would start by not even using the DataReceived handler. Just send your command and then sit in a loop until you receive *some kind of response*. This way, you can verify that you have correctly configured the serial port and are sending the right command data.